# Problems with 'slider' function in R

Tags: r, compiler-errors, syntax-error

today i have a some sort of problem with function *'slider'* in R (using R studio 3.1.1).
Here is a error's text:

> Error in slider(62, 74, step = 0.5) : unused argument (step = 0.5)

I'm trying to use this function without this parametr, but it show me a new error:

> Error in tclVar(sl.defaults[i]) :
>
> argument "sl.defaults" is missing, with no default

And send me to traceback!
Where is a problem?

p.s. here is my code:

```
    library(manipulate)
library(UsingR)
data(galton)

myHist <- function(mu) {
 hist(galton$child, col = "red", breaks = 100)
 lines(c(mu, mu), c(0, 150), col = "green", lwd = 5)
 mse <- mean((galton$child - mu)^2)
 text(63, 150, paste("mu = ", mu))
 text(63, 150, paste("MSE = ", round(mse, 2)))
}

manipulate(myHist(mu), mu = slider(62, 74, step = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the slider function in the 'aplpack' library.

You need to specify that the slider function is coming from manipulate.

```
manipulate(myHist(mu), mu = manipulate::slider(62, 74, step = 1))
```

To see this, try typing in just the function with no arguments to the console.

```
> slider
function code ...
<environment: namespace:aplpack>
```

Edit: I also rewrote your myHist function using ggplot2 which is more powerful than the base plotting package. It's a good package to learn so hopefully this code can help you get started.

```
myHist <- function(mu) {

  mse <- mean((galton$child - mu) ^ 2)
  qplot(galton$child, binwidth = 0.1) + geom_vline(xintercept = mu, color = "red") + 
    annotate("text", x = 65, y = 150, label = paste("mu = ", mu)) +
    annotate("text", x = 65, y = 145, label = paste("MSE = ", round(mse, 2)))

}
```